# SQL to Combine Grouped data in to one new unique value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am importing some data that contains a text field that normally has the same information for every child record.

e.g.

```
ID  |  PID | VALUE 
1   |  1   | The quick brown fox
2   |  1   | The quick brown fox
3   |  1   | The quick brown fox
4   |  1   | The quick brown fox
```

However, as it is a free text field, sometimes the content gets modified:

```
2   |  1     | The quick*est* brown fox
3   |  1     | The quick brown fox *jumped over the log*
```

The data should really live with the parent entity and as such I need to get a merged version of the data that I can update the parent record with, like:

```
PID | Value
1   | The quickest brown fox jumped over the log
```

Sure I could use a cursor to loop over the data and create a merged result however I am importing 1000's of records and would prefer to do it as part of the import batch.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would clearly show us sample input and the exact output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to do some fairly complex string diff/merging. SQL Server doesn't do complex string manipulation, you're pretty much limited to concatenation, inserts (stuff), and a few other basic functions.  Merge isn't one of them.

It may be worth the effort to write a CLR procedure to do this for you, as you'll have access to a much wider range of string merge tools [like this one](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/). However, you may be less than satisfied with the results.  And what do you do if there's a conflict?  eg.

```
The quick brown fox jumped
The quick brown fox jumps
The quick brown fox danced
```

You'll need to manually determine the outcome of this sort of thing.  It may be better to just import a distinct list of all strings associated with each parent ID into a separate table which can then be looked up, or at a later date merged with a bit of human oversight.

Comment: Thanks @pcdev, yeah I was pretty sure that conflicts were going to be an issue, thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is basically to update the smallest `id`(the initial record) of each `PID` group, with the value of the largest `id` (the latest record) for the given `PID` group.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[PID] TINYINT
   ,[VALUE] VARCHAR(250)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [PID], [VALUE])
VALUES (1, 1, 'The quick brown fox')
      ,(2, 1, 'The quick brown fox is red')
      ,(3, 1, 'The quick brown fox is dead')
      --
      ,(4, 2, 'cat')
      ,(5, 2, 'cat is now dog')
      --
      ,(6, 3, 'cow is born');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [PID]
          ,MAX([ID]) AS [value_to_get]
          ,MIN([ID]) AS [value_to_set]
    FROM @DataSource
    GROUP BY [PID]
)
UPDATE @DataSource  
SET [VALUE] = (SELECT VGet.[VALUE] FROM @DataSource VGet WHERE VSet.[value_to_get] = VGet.[ID])
FROM @DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource VSet
    ON DS1.[ID] = VSet.[value_to_set];

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as @pcdev points conflicts can be an issue and this method will not deal with potential conflicts.

Comment: @adamc-au For example? Could you post some data in conflict and desired output?